# How to open/close antd Submenu programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have two components, ParentComponent and a child component called SelectionTool. The child component SelectionTool have and SubMenu item which is disabled and not collapsed by default. Disabled SubMenu can be enabled using a prop. What I'm trying to do is, I need to collapse/expand the SubMenu once it's enabled via the prop. Here is my code. I tried using `defaultOpenKeys` attribute in the ParentComponent Menu item. but it's not working. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Parent component**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Layout, Menu} from 'antd'
import SelectionTool from '../selection-tool/SelectionTool'

const {Sider} = Layout

const ParentComponent = props => {
    const [defaultOpenKeys, setDefaultOpenKeys] = useState([])

    return (
        <Sider
            width={240}
            defaultCollapsed={false}
            collapsedWidth={80}
            theme="light" trigger={null} collapsible>

            <Menu theme="light" mode="inline" defaultOpenKeys={defaultOpenKeys}>

                <SelectionTool setDefaultOpenKeys={setDefaultOpenKeys} />
            </Menu>
        </Sider>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent
```

**Child Component**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Menu } from 'antd'
const { SubMenu } = Menu

const SelectionTool = (props) => {
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true)
    const { setDefaultOpenKeys, selectionToolIsDisable, ...submenuProps } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsDisabled(selectionToolIsDisable)
    }, [selectionToolIsDisable])

    useEffect(() => {
        isDisabled && setDefaultOpenKeys([submenuProps.eventKey])
    }, [isDisabled])

    return(
        <SubMenu 
            title="Selection tools" 
            deisabled={isDisabled}
            key={submenuProps.eventKey} 
            {...submenuProps}>
            <Menu.Item>Menu item 1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>Menu item 2</Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
    )
}

export default SelectionTool
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution myself. This solved my issue:-

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd'
import SelectionTool from '../selection-tool/SelectionTool'

const { Sider } = Layout

const ParentComponent = props => {
    const [openKeys, setOpenKeys] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectionToolIsDisable) {
            const openedKeyIndex = openKeys.indexOf('menu1')
        if (openedKeyIndex !== -1) {
            const _openKeys = [...openKeys]
            _openKeys.splice(openedKeyIndex, 1)
            setOpenKeys(_openKeys)
        }

    } else {
        setOpenKeys([...openKeys, 'menu1'])
    }

}, [selectionToolIsDisable])

const onOpenChange = _openKeys => {
    setOpenKeys([..._openKeys])
}

return (
    <Sider
        width={240}
        defaultCollapsed={false}
        collapsedWidth={80}
        theme="light" trigger={null} collapsible>

        <Menu
            theme="light"
            mode="inline"
            openKeys={openKeys}
            onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
            key="menu1">

            <SelectionTool selectionToolIsDisable={selectionToolIsDisable} />
        </Menu>
    </Sider>
)
}

export default ParentComponent
```